# Embed VLC player in GWT

Tags: javascript, gwt, video, embed, vlc

I want to embed a VLC player in my webapp build with Google's GWT.

First I had a look at this page: http://wiki.videolan.org/GWT, which offers a nice solution but I add to implements all javascript functions calls (play, stop, fullscreen) with JSNI.

Then I found gwt-player (hosted by Google code) which does all the job for me but the annoying part is that the project is not widely used (few posts each month on the project's group, not so many talks about it in blogs/forums...)

Do you know another option to easly embed & control a VLC player in a GWT app ?

My main goal is to play any video/audio file in a webapp and offer the user a fast/forward feature (set rate in VLC), is there any other player I could use ?
I already had a look at Quicktime, Windows Media player & Flowplayer, none of them offers as much features as VLC.

Thanks in advance & have a nice new year's eve.

Chris

Comment: Embedding any media player in a web app is an exercise in incompatbility, frustration, and security holes for the end-user. This is why the vast majority of sites have migrated to Flash video instead (with HTML5 video maybe coming in the future). I personally wouldn't ever recommend installing VLC as a plugin as it exposes as net-facing an enormous range of formats and codecs from diverse authors; there are definitely going to be security holes in there as there have been many in the past.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can look at https://github.com/revolunet/VLCcontrols its pure javascript but embeds VLC controls for you. May be inspiring.

Answer (score 0):

Try out the BST player:

http://oss.bramosystems.com/bst-player/index.html

[Playing media with gwt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9736402/playing-media-with-gwt/9738783#9738783)