# Playing media with gwt

Tags: gwt, servlets, video, html5-video, vlc

I have a simple mail system developed with G.W.T and i am trying add a feature to play  audio and video files if there is a video or audio file comes as an attachment.

I have been trying bst player and HTML video tag to get work , but i can not play some video formats such as .avi, .mpeg ,.mpg and so on.

What else can be done to play those kind of video formats?

On the other hand, i am thinking of converting the video file in a java servlet then giving that url to player, but i do not know if that makes sense.Is that should be the way?

Last thing is; is there a general format (maybe .flv?) that a video file first have to be converted into so it can be playable by VlcPlayerPlugin or another video player? Any other tip will be helpful.

Thank you for your helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for the delay, did not have the chance to reply.Because of VlcPlayer was behaving strange and showing different control buttons on Ubuntu and Windows, i decided to use FlashPlayerPlugin of BstPlayer.I first convert file to flv by using [jave](http://www.sauronsoftware.it/projects/jave/manual.php?PHPSESSID=059ifbragk81gfu265aagn3cj4) is described here in documentation, then it serves the converted video to FlashPlayer, it works without problem now , thank you all for your helps.

Answer (score 0):

the html5 video tag can only play certain formats. You can find a list of the supported browser formats here.

Answer (score 0):

I also had some problems with the BST player but at least it worked with the following code:

```
public YoutubeVideoPopup( String youtubeUrl )
{
    // PopupPanel's constructor takes 'auto-hide' as its boolean parameter.
    // If this is set, the panel closes itself automatically when the user
    // clicks outside of it.
    super( true );
    this.setAnimationEnabled( true );

    Widget player = null;
    try
    {
        player = new YouTubePlayer( youtubeUrl, "500", "375" );
        player.setStyleName( "player" );
    }
    catch ( PluginVersionException e )
    {
        // catch plugin version exception and alert user to download plugin first.
        // An option is to use the utility method in PlayerUtil class.
        player = PlayerUtil.getMissingPluginNotice( Plugin.Auto, "Missing Plugin",
            "You have to install a flash plaxer first!",
            false );
    }
    catch ( PluginNotFoundException e )
    {
        // catch PluginNotFoundException and tell user to download plugin, possibly providing
        // a link to the plugin download page.
        player = new HTML( "You have to install a flash plaxer first!" );
    }
    setWidget( player );
}
```

As you can see, we used the youtube player here, which has the positive effect that the vide can be placed at youtube and must not be pished to server every time the GWT app is redeployed. 
You also can play flash other formats, simply use the correct Player class in the try block; example for flash:

```
player = new com.bramosystems.oss.player.core.client.ui.FlashMediaPlayer( GWT.getHostPageBaseURL( ) +
            f4vFileName, true, "375", "500" );
    player.setWidth( 500 + "px" );
    player.setHeight( "100%" );
```